# How do you make minecraft run smoother and get more FPS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a HP Envy All in One, running Windows 8 I believe. I use mods such as optifine, potion counter, direction hud and togglesneak. Anyways, whenever I'm running around regularly, I get around 60 fps, whenever I start to PvP, it drops down to around 30 to 40. Anyways, how could I end . up getting more FPS? Would I need to upgrade anything? Need to get a new PC (because I'm most likely buying one soon anyways) Just let me know, thanks.